Is there a way to print 2 characters in one space within console?
So, I am attempting to make a maze game for some coursework at college. I have managed to get a maze generation algorithm working which makes use of recursive backtracking. However, the issue with this algorithm is that is does not use separate spaces (I don't know what else to call them) in the console to allow for space for a character to move within the maze.
Here is the code for the program which is written in C# and runs exclusively within console:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace Prototype
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static int N = 1;
        static int S = 2;
        static int E = 4;
        static int W = 8;

        static Dictionary<char, int> sides = new Dictionary<char, int>() { {'N', 1}, { 'S', 2 }, { 'E', 4 }, { 'W', 8 } };
        static Dictionary<char, int> directionX = new Dictionary<char, int>() { { 'E', 1 }, { 'W', -1 }, { 'N', 0 }, { 'S', 0 } };
        static Dictionary<char, int> directionY = new Dictionary<char, int>() { { 'E', 0 }, { 'W', 0 }, { 'N', -1 }, { 'S', 1 } };
        static Dictionary<char, int> opposite = new Dictionary<char, int>() { { 'E', W }, { 'W', E }, { 'N', S }, { 'S', N } };

        static Random rand = new Random();

        static void RandomDirection(char[] array)
        {
            for (int i = array.Length - 1; i > 0; i--)
            {
                int j = rand.Next(i + 1);
                char temp = array[i];
                array[i] = array[j];
                array[j] = temp;
            }
        }
        static void MazeGen(int cx, int cy, int[,] grid)
        {
            char[] directions = new char[] { 'N', 'S', 'E', 'W' };
            RandomDirection(directions);

            for (int i = 0; i < directions.Length; i++)
            {
                char direction = directions[i];
                int nx = cx + directionX[direction];
                int ny = cy + directionY[direction];

                if ((ny >= 0 && ny < grid.GetLength(0)) && (nx >= 0 && nx < grid.GetLength(1)) && grid[ny, nx] == 0)
                {
                    grid[cy, cx] |= sides[direction];
                    grid[ny, nx] |= opposite[direction];
                    MazeGen(nx, ny, grid);
                }
            }
        }
        static string PrintMaze(int[,] grid, int startRow, int finishRow)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append(" ");
            for (int i = 0; i < (grid.GetLength(1) * 2 - 1); i++)
            {
                sb.Append("_");
            }
            sb.AppendLine();
            for (int i = 0; i < grid.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                if (i != startRow)
                {
                    sb.Append("|");
                }
                else
                {
                    sb.Append(" ");
                }

                for (int j = 0; j < grid.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    if ((grid[i, j] & S) != 0)
                    {
                        sb.Append(" ");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        sb.Append("_");
                    }

                    if ((grid[i, j] & E) != 0)
                    {
                        if (((grid[i, j] | grid[i, j + 1]) & S) != 0)
                        {
                            sb.Append(" ");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            sb.Append("_");
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (i == finishRow && j == grid.GetLength(0) - 1)
                        {
                            sb.Append(" ");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                             sb.Append("|");
                        }
                    }
                    
                }
                sb.AppendLine();                
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the size of the maze: ");
            int mazeSizeInput = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            int[,] grid = new int[mazeSizeInput, mazeSizeInput];
            MazeGen(0, 0, grid);

            int startRow = rand.Next(mazeSizeInput);
            int finishRow = rand.Next(mazeSizeInput);

            string maze = PrintMaze(grid, startRow, finishRow);
            Console.WriteLine(maze);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}

This image represents what is displayed in console when the program is run. As you can see, the "_" characters used for the floor do not leave any room for another character representing the player to be displayed.
Is there anyway to display 2 ASCII characters within the same square in the console?

You have to reserve the space for character to be or not to be. Old approach (used in old PCs, like ZX-Spectrum, to save video RAM) was pseudographics to draw more than one pixel inside character, like this: ▀▄█  Not sure if you can do same on modern PC without designing a font first.

Recently I learned about zalgo text, maybe it can also be used to overlap player character over the maze wall characters somehow? The console should support Unicode, not all consoles do.

You're trying to address a symptom rather than the underlying problem.  The underlying problem is that your current approach doesn't meaningfully distinguish between "there's a wall here" and "there's no wall here".  I'd recommend taking some steps back and designing the maze data structure to more simply indicate this first.  Once you have a logical representation of the maze, create separate logic for displaying that representation to humans.  Currently you started with an ambiguous display standard and kept adding complexity to the logic to support that standard.

I would not look for overlaying characters and similar tricks.
You have already used alternating columns such that vertical walls always appear at even horizontal offsets, while the cells between them are at odd offsets.
If you would apply the same principle vertically, you'd get something like this:
┌───┬───────────────┐
│   │               │
├─┐ │ ╶─┬─────┬───╴ │
│ │ │   │     │     │
│ ╵ ├─╴ │ ┌─┐ │ ┌─╴ │
│   │   │ │ │ │ │   │
│ ╶─┤ ╶─┤ │ │ │ └───┤
│   │   │ │ │ │     │
└─┐ ├───┤ │ ╵ │ ┌─┐ │
  │ │   │ │   │ │ │ │
╷ │ ╵ ╷ │ └─┐ │ ╵ │ │
│ │   │ │   │ │   │ │
│ └───┤ │ ╷ │ ├───┘ ╵
│     │ │ │ │ │     
│ ╷ ┌─┘ │ │ │ ╵ ┌─╴ ╷
│ │ │   │ │ │   │   │
│ ├─┘ ┌─┴─┘ ├───┘ ┌─┤
│ │   │     │     │ │
│ ╵ ╶─┘ ┌───┘ ╶───┘ │
│       │           │
└───────┴───────────┘

This would solve your problem, as now you can place another character on every cell that can be visited. But it is quite stretched vertically on most consoles, as these characters typically take more vertical space than horizontal space.
To counter that effect, you could add more characters in the horizontal direction, so that each free cell takes three spaces instead of one:
┌───────┬───────────────────────────────┐
│       │                               │
├───┐   │   ╶───┬───────────┬───────╴   │
│   │   │       │           │           │
│   ╵   ├───╴   │   ┌───┐   │   ┌───╴   │
│       │       │   │   │   │   │       │
│   ╶───┤   ╶───┤   │   │   │   └───────┤
│       │       │   │   │   │           │
└───┐   ├───────┤   │   ╵   │   ┌───┐   │
    │   │       │   │       │   │   │   │
╷   │   ╵   ╷   │   └───┐   │   ╵   │   │
│   │       │   │       │   │       │   │
│   └───────┤   │   ╷   │   ├───────┘   ╵
│           │   │   │   │   │           
│   ╷   ┌───┘   │   │   │   ╵   ┌───╴   ╷
│   │   │       │   │   │       │       │
│   ├───┘   ┌───┴───┘   ├───────┘   ┌───┤
│   │       │           │           │   │
│   ╵   ╶───┘   ┌───────┘   ╶───────┘   │
│               │                       │
└───────────────┴───────────────────────┘

I think that looks nice enough. Here is the code for that:
    static string PrintMaze(int[,] grid, int startRow, int finishRow)
    {
        int height = grid.GetLength(0);
        int width = grid.GetLength(1);
        int[,] spots = new int[height*2+1, width*2+1];

        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
                int cell = grid[i, j];
                if ((cell & N) == 0) {
                    spots[i*2  , j*2  ] |= E;
                    spots[i*2  , j*2+1] |= E | W;
                    spots[i*2  , j*2+2] |= W;
                }
                if ((cell & S) == 0) {
                    spots[i*2+2, j*2  ] |= E;
                    spots[i*2+2, j*2+1] |= E | W;
                    spots[i*2+2, j*2+2] |= W;
                }
                if ((cell & E) == 0 && (j < width - 1 || i != finishRow)) {
                    spots[i*2  , j*2+2] |= S;
                    spots[i*2+1, j*2+2] |= N | S;
                    spots[i*2+2, j*2+2] |= N;
                }
                if ((cell & W) == 0 && (j > 0 || i != startRow)) {
                    spots[i*2  , j*2  ] |= S;
                    spots[i*2+1, j*2  ] |= N | S;
                    spots[i*2+2, j*2  ] |= N;
                }
            }
        }
        
        String crosses = " ╵╷│╶└┌├╴┘┐┤─┴┬┼";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i <= height*2; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j <= width*2; j++)
            {
                sb.Append(crosses[spots[i, j]], 1 + (j % 2)*2); // stretch horizontally
            }
            sb.AppendLine();
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }


@Maskd, any feedback on this answer? Does it suit your needs?
